# How to install ubuntu 12.10 on windows Virtual PC?

Tags: windows

I'm having trouble installing ubuntu 12.10 on a Virtual PC. I've got 12.04 to boot and mounted it onto the virtual disk but there seems to be a problem with networking. Everytime I create the virtual disk for 12.10 it says its not large enough even though it is way over the required disk space. The disk is a fixed size not expanding.

Comment: Please tell us why you suspect "a problem with networking".

Answer (score 1):

Windows Virtual PC exists solely to emulate other (usually earlier) versions of Windows.

To run Ubuntu 12.10 on a virtual machine you should download VMware Player:

http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html

Or Virtual Box:

https://www.virtualbox.org/